# how to print a receipt in java label

Tags: printing, jlabel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05AcM.png)i want to print all the Double variables in    a java label. but when i execute the program only Qty1 print in the label.so that i used escape sequences but the also dont work. Could anyone tell me how to fix this.What i really expect to do is something like in the attachment.

[image]

**Code**

```
JButton receipt = new JButton("Receipt");
        receipt.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Double Qty1= Double.parseDouble(textField.getText());
                Double Qty2=Double.parseDouble(textField_2.getText());
                Double Qty3=Double.parseDouble(textField_3.getText());
                lblRecipt.setText("\t\nHotel \n\nManagement System"+Qty1);
            //  lblRecipt.setText("Hotel Management System"+Qty1);
```

Comment: What's the output now?

Comment: just "Hotel Management System"and the variable qty.

Comment: Do you mean you need newlines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use swing's html formatting feature as explained in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html.

> To specify that a component's text has HTML formatting, just put the  tag at the beginning of the text, then use any valid HTML in the remainder.

This is what swing example offers:
[image: HTML Example]

Your code might look like:

```
lblRecipt.setText("<html>\t<br>Hotel<br><br>Management System"+Qty1+"</html>");
```

Comment: Dear Thomas, Thank you for the support.it works for me.thanks